# Is there any existing opensource JavaCard applet emulating the functionality of Mifare classic?

Tags: javacard, mifare, contactless-smartcard

Is there any existing opensource JavaCard applet emulating the functionality of **Mifare** classic?

Comment: (AFAIK) You probably can't emulate MIFARE Classic with an applet, but there definitely are java cards with MIFARE Classic support (via [Memory](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacardx/external/Memory.html) or some other proprietary API/ways). Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible because Mifare Classic uses ISO/IEC 14443-3 and all available JavaCard can handle only ISO/IEC 14443-4

Comment: Just a note: (AFAIK) The MIFARE Classic's Crypto-1 works below the ISO 14443-3 layer so you won't see ISO 14443-3 frames in the air after the authentication. MIFARE Classic communication protocol thus does not comply with ISO/IEC 14443-3.